# google app script messages[j].isUnread()

Tags: javascript

I wrote a function which scans my email for unread threads with under a common subject, and then filtering only unread messages under these threads

```
  var searchstring = "is:unread from:paypal subject:mysubject";
  var threads = GmailApp.search(searchstring);
  var UnreadMessageCount = GmailApp.getInboxUnreadCount();
        if(UnreadMessageCount > 0)
        {
           if (threads.length > 0)
           {
               for (var i in threads)
               {
                 var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
                 for (var j in messages)
                 {
                   if(messages[j].isUnread())
                   {
                         var Content = messages[j].getPlainBody();
                         var ContentLength = Content.length;
                         var ItemIDIndex = Content.indexOf("Item");
                         Do something...
                   }
                 }
             }
         }
```

the problem is that ***messages[j].isUnread()*** is sometimes true even though I know for a fact that I do not have any unread messages in my mailbox

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking messages[j].isUnread() is returning empty object if you don't have any unread messages. Try to use

```js
if (messages[j].isUnread().length) {
return true;
}
```

.length property instead.